# weighted edgelist into directed and undirected graph in r

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following weighted edgelist `el`

```
structure(list(from = c(1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1003L, 1003L
), to = c(1002L, 1003L, 1001L, 1003L, 1001L, 1002L), weight = c(2L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("from", "to", "weight"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to create a few visualizations: (1) a directed graph where the weights are used to thicken the lines between two given nodes, (2) an undirected graph that sums all of the interactions (`weight`s) together and produces the same graph, and graphs that recreate (1) and (2) without using the weights.

for (1) I use

```
directed_graph_wgt <- graph.data.frame(el, directed = TRUE)
plot(directed_graph,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,edge.width=E(directed_graph)$weight/2)
```

but the resulting graph does has a line on `1003` which is wrong because in the data they have no interactions

I have a similar issue with the undirected

```
 undirected_graph_wgt <- as.undirected(directed_graph, mode = "collapse", edge.attr.comb = "sum")
plot(undirected_graph_wgt)
```

I think what is going on is that `weight=0` is not doing what I think it is (signifying no link)

Also I am not sure why the nodes are not spread out on the page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, consider the following options.

```
################################################################### FIRST OPTION

el <- data.frame(from = c(1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1003L, 1003L),
                 to = c(1002L, 1003L, 1001L, 1003L, 1001L, 1002L),
                 weight = c(2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L))
el
# This design of edgelist implies that there are links between (i) 1003 and 1001
# and between (ii) 1003 and 1002 but the weight of those links is 0
library(igraph)
directed_graph_wgt <- graph.data.frame(el, directed = TRUE)
# the adjacency matrix of your network looks like this
adj.mat <- as_adjacency_matrix(directed_graph_wgt, type = "both", names = TRUE,
                               sparse = FALSE)
adj.mat # as you can see, the adjacency_matrix shows links between 
# (i) 1003 and 1001 and and between (ii) 1003 and 1002

                                ### IMPORTANT ### 
# When you move from an adjacency matrix to a graph, you might consider
# that a "weight" of 0 in the matrix leads to no interaction (edge) between nodes. 
# But be careful,  the adjacency matrix is actually a relationnal matrix
# (or connection matrix), not just a weights matrix. It actually provides the 
# number of edges between nodes from the graph.
# Therefore, when you are designing your graph.data.frame, your must include 
# ONLY connected nodes

# Something like this should be relevent here
nodes <-  c(1001L, 1002L, 1003L) # create a vector of nodes 
nodes # we have three nodes
el <- data.frame(from = c(1001L, 1002L),
                 to = c(1002L, 1001L),
                 weight = c(2L, 1L)) # use ONLY connected nodes
el # structrure of links
# Now, you can include all the nodes in the network with the "vertices" argument

# (1) directed graph
directed_graph_wgt <- graph.data.frame(el, directed = TRUE,
                                       vertices = nodes)
# the right adjacency matrix of your network looks like this
adj.mat <- as_adjacency_matrix(directed_graph_wgt, type = "both", names = TRUE,
                               sparse = FALSE)
adj.mat # as you can see, the adjacency matrix shows all the nodes 
# and here is the plot
plot(directed_graph_wgt, layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold,
     edge.width = E(directed_graph_wgt)$weight/2)

# (2) undirected graph
undirected_graph_wgt <- as.undirected(directed_graph_wgt, mode = "collapse",
                                      edge.attr.comb = "sum")
plot(undirected_graph_wgt)


### KEYPOINT
# When you are designing your own edgelist, setting a weight as 0 means that 
# the weight of the considered link is 0, not that the link doesn't exist. 
# However, a 0 in the adjacency matrix leads to no interaction (edge)
# between nodes.

# It looks like you are confusing "weights" and "number of interactions". Even 
# though both can be used interchangeably, you must be careful when using them
# in igraph functions


################################################################## SECOND OPTION

# To use the weights in "el" as indicator of relations, you need to consider
# the assumption that weight == 0 means no link.
# You can use the delete_edges() function

el <- data.frame(from = c(1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1003L, 1003L),
                 to = c(1002L, 1003L, 1001L, 1003L, 1001L, 1002L),
                 weight = c(2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L))
el #t this is your initial edgelist

# (1) directed graph
directed_graph_wgt <- graph.data.frame(el, directed = TRUE)
directed_graph_wgt
# use delete_edges() to consider ONLY weight != 0 (no link)
# We will remove link with weight == 0 (i.e no link)
directed_graph_wgt2 <- delete_edges(directed_graph_wgt,
                                    which(E(directed_graph_wgt)$weight == 0))
plot(directed_graph_wgt2, layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold,
     edge.width = E(directed_graph_wgt)$weight/2)

# (2) undirected graph
undirected_graph_wgt <- as.undirected(directed_graph_wgt, mode = "collapse",
                                      edge.attr.comb = "sum")
undirected_graph_wgt2 <- delete_edges(undirected_graph_wgt,
                                      which(E(undirected_graph_wgt)$weight == 0))
plot(undirected_graph_wgt2)
```

Comment: Am I right that if I had a very large database (N = 5 million) that option one is less automated? I may be missing something. Also, in my graphs, I would like isolates to be shown, that is why I am using `weight == 0`. Option 2 would seem to delete isolates, is this assumption wrong?

Comment: Yes with such large database, the second option is more appropriate. This option (as well as option 1) will not delete isolated nodes; it deletes links with `weight == 0`. In this example you can see that node `1003` is still present in the network even though its has no link.

Comment: I am getting an error with your code: `directed_graph_wgt2 <- delete.edges(directed_graph_wgt,
+                                     which(E(directed_graph_wgt)$weight == 0))
Error in delete.edges(directed_graph_wgt, which(E(directed_graph_wgt)$weight ==  : 
  delete.edges requires an argument of class network.`

Comment: It is `delete_edges` and not delete.edges` for me at least using `igraph`

Comment: Also, the `as.undirected(directed_graph_wgt, mode = "collapse",
                                      edge.attr.comb = "sum")` line errors out when I have a date variable. Of course, the original omitted this but I would appreciate if there is a way for the program to ignore this variable or at least to point it to the weight column

Comment: You are right, I wanted you to use `delete_edges` instead of `delete.edges`. But they basically do the same job (see [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/network/versions/1.13.0/topics/deletion.methods)). I will edit my answer.

Comment: Concerning your second comment, when using `graph.data.frame` columns after the first two ones of the data frame are considered as edge attributes. Therefore, in your casee, you should take the first three columns to create `directed_graph_wgt`like this `directed_graph_wgt <- graph.data.frame(el[,  1:3], directed = TRUE)` or just ignore the `date` variable like this `directed_graph_wgt <- graph.data.frame(subset(el, select = -c(date)), directed = TRUE)`. After filtering your dataframe, `as.undirected` should work fine.